# Drupal 6.22 Facebook Login Module

Tags: facebook, drupal-6

I got 4 **FacebookLogin** modules in Drupal. Can anyone please suggest which module is the easiest to use.

Answer (score 0):

http://drupal.org/project/fb has been working well for me.  Recently there was an issue where FB sent emails out to all using the API because of some security issue with keys being passed in the URL, but the latest release fixed that.

Comment: will it work like facebook login is working in stackoverflow?